# Components Behaviour in Gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm a Java Backend Developer, and now I try to use an GridbagLayout in my Application, and....yeah, I failed.

I have an Login Screen with Username, Password, Remember Me, login button etc. and I want that it look like this:

[image: Sorey, 5 Minutes in paint...]

But all what I get from the layout is this :

[image]

So I want to ask you explicit to correct my code, maybe I understand how this Layout works.

Here is the Code:

```
    add(loginnameLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 5, 5));

    add(loginname, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 5, 5));

    add(passwortLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 5, 5));

    add(passwordfield, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 5, 5));

    add(rememberLogin, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 5, 5));

    add(einloggenButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 5, 5));
```

Sorry about the circumstances, but I'm not sure that I can solve it alone.

Comment: `GridBagLayout`  is rarely used today. Use the old fashioned simplified `GridLayout`.

Comment: Change all of the weight values to 0.0.  GridBagLayout is widely used today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because @OP is looking for code correction, rather than the answer to the question

Comment: @god Well I must be doing something wrong, `GridBagLayout` is about the most used layout manager I use (and `GridLayout` is just down right ugly for this type of task :P)

Comment: Change the `weightx` and `weighty` parameters of `GridBagConstraints` to `0`, these determine how much of the remaining space is distributed to the components